# ubuntu keeps overriding a package installed with dpkg

Tags: apt, dpkg, deb

I compiled a custom gnu screen deb pkg and installed with dpkg -i, but after some time I noticed screens' version got back to one from ubuntu's repo.
I tried to run apt-mark hold screen before overriding screen with my package, that did not work.
Then I tried to do the same but first install my package and then run apt mark hold - did not work either.
Also tried to purge the ubuntu's package and then install mine, did not work.
Also I tried to add a rule blocking screen installation to /etc/apt/preferences.d, still no luck.
What to try next to make ubuntu to not touch my custom packages?
Thanks in advance

ubuntu 20.04 lts

Comment: More specifics are needed. Ex. What is the package name, what are its dependencies, which package(s) is overriding your package, etc.

Comment: @Nmath gnu screen, the package name is `screen`. depends on libc6 libcrypt libpam libtinfo libutempter

Comment: There's already a package by that name, so your package manager is going to replace your package with the most up-to-date version in repos.  Can you use another name for your package?

Comment: @Nmath yeah, thought about that. What I do not like it that screen is referenced in some metapackages; if I install them, my executable/shared libs will get overriden. I'm not sure if I understand the current behaviour of apt mark and cannot rely on that ubuntu's version wont get installed.

Comment: and I do not want to workaround, but find a complete solution

Comment: Renaming an app is not a workaround :) Mind that a version is overwritten if the version number of the new one is higher... so compile yours with a higher number than screen would ever use and it wont get overwritten (but THAT is a workaround).

Comment: Best solution would be to name your package screen-mine-$version  and have it install in /usr/local/ or /opt/screen-mine so that both versions could co-exist.

Comment: can you show `apt-cache policy screen` ?